# Unable to Locate File syscall_table_32.S

Tags: kernel

I am using Ubuntu 12 & kernel version is 3.8.0

i want to add personal syscall but unable to locate the file mentioned above.

path i am trying is `usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic/arch/x86/kernel`

i also tried `usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic/arch/x86/syscalls`

i also tried `usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19/arch/x86/kernel`

i looked for solution in this web, stack exchange & google but still unable :(

please help

Comment: Don't you mean `syscalls_32.h`? It's here: `/usr/src/linux-headers-<kernel-version>/arch/x86/include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h`. Make sure you've installed the Linux kernel headers and try `find /usr/src -name "syscalls_32.h"` Or maybe just `/usr/include/syscall.h`, or `/usr/src/linux-headers-<version>/arch/x86/syscalls/syscalltbl.sh`?

Comment: /usr/include/syscall.h that was it :) Thanks @qertydijk :D

Answer (score 2):

For locating files already installed you can use `dpkg -S`

```
$ dpkg -S syscall
gdb: /usr/share/gdb/syscalls
gdb: /usr/share/gdb/syscalls/sparc-linux.xml
manpages-dev: /usr/share/man/man2/_syscall.2.gz
gdb: /usr/share/gdb/syscalls/gdb-syscalls.dtd
gdb: /usr/share/gdb/syscalls/ppc64-linux.xml
gdb: /usr/share/gdb/syscalls/sparc64-linux.xml
gdb: /usr/share/gdb/syscalls/mips-n32-linux.xml
perl: /usr/lib/perl/5.14.2/bits/syscall.ph
manpages-dev: /usr/share/man/man2/syscalls.2.gz
gdb: /usr/share/gdb/syscalls/amd64-linux.xml
gdb: /usr/share/gdb/syscalls/i386-linux.xml
perl: /usr/lib/perl/5.14.2/syscall.ph
libc6-dev:i386: /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/syscall.h
perl: /usr/lib/perl/5.14.2/sys/syscall.ph
manpages-dev: /usr/share/man/man2/afs_syscall.2.gz
manpages-dev: /usr/share/man/man2/syscall.2.gz
gdb: /usr/share/gdb/syscalls/mips-o32-linux.xml
gdb: /usr/share/gdb/syscalls/ppc-linux.xml
libc6-dev:i386: /usr/include/syscall.h
gdb: /usr/share/gdb/syscalls/mips-n64-linux.xml
libc6-dev:i386: /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/syscall.h
linux-libc-dev:i386: /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/asm/vsyscall.h
```

For locating files that are not provided by installed packages you can try `locate` (if the file is recent enough:

```
$ locate syscall.h
/usr/include/syscall.h
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/asm/vsyscall.h
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/syscall.h
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/syscall.h
```

If neither of those shows results, you can try a search in the [Ubuntu Package Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=syscall_table_32.S&mode=exactfilename&suite=raring&arch=any):

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=name of file&mode=exactfilename&suite=raring&arch=any
```

If you want a *"local"* solution use `apt-file`:

```
sudo apt-get -y install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
apt-file search name_of_file
```

Comment: main file i was looking for is the file that contains all the system calls but still unable to find out in any kernel. i tried 3 to 4 kernels

Answer (score -1):

Hey try this from the terminal

```
find /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic/ -type f -name "syscall_table_32.S"
```

if you get permission errors try running the command as **sudo**

Good luck!

Comment: command worked without sudo but it just returned empty :/

Comment: This file [does not exist in Ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=syscall_table_32.S&mode=exactfilename&suite=raring&arch=any), so this answer is pointless. And @CodingNoob, did you install the Linux kernel headers?

Comment: @qervtvdijk i tried to install 2.6.37.3 & reboot system with that but i was unable to do so & for 3.8.0 i did not downloaded anything :/

Comment: Yes I searched my system first but I did not find it too. So as @gertvdijk says it might not be there. Good luck!

Comment: i have find the file thanks @mojo706 see upper comments right after my question for ref

Comment: I'm glad seems we were looking for the wrong file. Happy coding.

Comment: yes but my problem still persists cause i am unable to find any tutorial of adding system call in kernel 3.8 , have tutorial about old one but system is not starting with old one :'(

Comment: @CodingNoob need a little help? check out #ubuntu-kernel team on IRC (freenode) ask a question and you might get an answer just be patient.